# How to compare two array value and get matched inner array value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

how to compare two array value and remove the duplicate value from inner array also and store in another array using PHP. Array compared by array[name] and want to remove the related index in all the inner array.

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => detail12.docx
    [1] => resume.docx
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => detail12.docx
            [1] => document.pdf
            [2] => resume.docx
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
            [1] => application/pdf
            [2] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/php2LK7xC
            [1] => /tmp/phpTEWqXG
            [2] => /tmp/phpAKki0M
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30887
            [1] => 86118
            [2] => 30887
        )

)
```

Expected Output:-

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => detail12.docx
            [1] => resume.docx
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
            [1] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/php2LK7xC
            [1] => /tmp/phpAKki0M
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30887
            [1] => 30887
        )
)
```

I need the output as shown in the above Expected Output. Kindly give the code to get the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This method saves the keys that are not found in `name` with `array_search` and uses `foreach` to delete them later.

```
$a = ['detail12.docx', 'resume.docx'];
$b = [
    'name' => ['detail12.docx', 'document.pdf', 'resume.docx', 'test.php'],
    'type' => ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/pdf', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'test']
];
$keys = [];
foreach($b['name'] as $index => $value){
    if(array_search($value, $a) === false){
        $keys[] = $index;
    }
}
foreach($b as $index => $array){
    foreach($keys as $key){
        unset($b[$index][$key]);
    }
    $b[$index] = array_values($b[$index]);
}
print_r($b);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => detail12.docx
            [1] => resume.docx
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
            [1] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        )

)
```

[Fiddle of code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f8b0139bfdaa691db81489e862991f5ffd056f4) - [Image of result](https://ibb.co/WK89h4c)
Ps. Of course I created an example with a few entries just as a visual test

Reference:

- [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset)
- [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: It's working but its possible to get a array index in order like - [0] [1] Now its coming like - [0] [2]

Comment: Yes i add code, you need to add `array_values`

Comment: No it's not, [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f8b0139bfdaa691db81489e862991f5ffd056f4), have you copy again my code? i added a line.

Comment: You can see that array [0] and [2] its coming. So its showing error that (Message: array_values() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given). kindly tell me how to fix it.

Comment: [image of result](https://ibb.co/WK89h4c) <-- where you see [0][2] ??? it's correct and the code doesn't have problem.

Comment: Yes its coming correct in PHP Sandbox editor but when I am running in my server its showing like that (Message: array_values() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given) as warning message what to do?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? Anyway i suggest you to update to PHP 8

Comment: PHP Version - 7.4.23

Comment: It's really strange, the only idea i have is you have different array structure. can you give me your code or create a snippet with the error reproducible?

Comment: Can I get your mail id or any contact to share the code and details?

Comment: You can use [this website](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and use button Save or share

Comment: I can't send snippet image in that link.

Comment: I need complete code not image of code, use snippet i will see result.

Comment: Same above which you have coded I have applied. As I told If I run with PHP function online editor Its coming fine but only in my server its showing error. How can I show it to you tell me anyway.

Comment: I think you wrong config in your server.

Comment: Anyway the script work it's your internal problem, approve the answer and open new one with new problem.